# iFrame and Table changing styling of social icons

Tags: html, css

I've added an iFrame and Table to a blog post which seems to be changing the stlying of my social icons from a single horizontal line to a stack?

You can see a live example at: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/testing-for-stack/

Normal icons: [image]

Incorrect icons: [image]

HTML:

```
<h2>Which city takes the shortest time to save for a deposit?</h2>

<div>
<small><table style="text-align: center; width: 50%; float:right;" class="table-hover">
<tr><th>City</th><th>Years to save for a deposit - Single</th><th>Years to save for a deposit - Couple</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Southampton</td><td>0.72</td><td>0.29</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Belfast</td><td>0.83</td><td>0.39</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Manchester</td><td>0.93</td><td>0.38</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Derby</td><td>1.06</td><td>0.45</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Kingston upon Hull</td><td>1.07</td><td>0.45</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Sheffield</td><td>1.09</td><td>0.44</td></tr></table></small>


<iframe width="47%" height="300" src="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/1_XfUsaNLKggOW0VbHhcbbVCzfOYMPHdr/page/Fe4j" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="dummyClear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
td, th {
text-align: center;
}
th {font-weight: bold;}

.dummyClear{
   clear:both;
}

.panel-heading {
font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Specify a class for the table you're adding, and then prefix your css with that class name. E.g. `.myTable td, .myTable th { ... }`  You're probably overriding the page CSS with your new CSS.

Comment: unable to see your private iframe content, there is no way for us to check out what goes in the way. You probably are linking a page with a Responsive CSS library to style your social icon's links ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some errors in your page html code:

```
<style>
  td, th {
    text-align: center;
  }
  th {font-weight: bold;}</p>
    <p>.dummyClear{
    clear:both;
  }</p>
  <p>.panel-heading {Te
  font-style: italic;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Boom! Thanks, that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

In the live example the .social-icons width is set to 33.33%, just change it to at most 16% that the icons will be side by side.

Answer (score 0):

add all the 3 icon div's inside another single `div` with `width:100%`

here is the social-icon css

```
.social-icons {
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.33%;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
```

and the parent div css

```
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```